# How to set identifiers an integer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an API method that returns JSON floating-point identifiers (3971.0). Although in fact an integer (3971) should be output. How can this be remedied?

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  render json: @users
end
```

Comment: `"3971.0"` is a string, not a floating point value. I think the real question is "why are you storing integers as stringified floats?".

Comment: If you use `ActiveModel::Serializer` then it would be a easier approach to change that value

Comment: No, I do not use Serializer

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Okay, can you tell me how to fix it if I use Serializer

Comment: tbh @user10223422 I did not observe what muistooshort mentioned and if you fix that, you don't need serializer as well. You should not be storing integer as a string and to top it it's a float as well.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna In the sense of? I have the identifiers type "number". I use the Oracle database (there is no such thing as integer and float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to go with solution using ActiveModel::Serializer, then you can do it as

1. You need add this `gem 'active_model_serializers'`
2. You need create a serializer for your resource `rails g serializer user`
3. That will create a file `user_serializer.rb` under `app/serializer`
4. Inside the class, define the attributes in the following manner which you want to send back in your response `attributes :user_id, :login, :name, :spr_work_id`
5. Let's say you want to modify the value of :spr_work_id to make it an integer then you have to define a method inside the serializer as so

   ```
   def spr_work_id

     self.object.spr_work_id.to_i

   end
   ```

In your controller replace `render json: @users` to `@users.map{|user| UserSerializer.new(user).serializable_hash}`

Comment: Or just do `render json: @users` and it will pick `UserSerializer` by convention?